# How to map www.xyz.com:8080/myApp to www.mywebsite.com in Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat, url-mapping

I am using Tomcat 8

I can access application by typing `www.csxyz.com:8080/myApp` from any browser/machine

Now I need to access application if I type **www.myApp.com**

Comment: you have to forward your domain, i dont know from where you bought your domain .For example Godaddy provide an option for domain forwarding check the link `https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name?countrysite=in`.Ask your provider

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html